# Performance of select method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance

The select method in Ruby is simple and straight forward. It will select elements in an array matching a specific criteria.

For example,

```
>> x = [4,5,7,89,4,5,3,6,8,9,4,45,56,23,2,7,3,5,4,224,234,565,546,345,23,234,234,234,23466,25,54]
x = [4,5,7,89,4,5,3,6,8,9,4,45,56,23,2,7,3,5,4,224,234,565,546,345,23,234,234,234,23466,25,54]
=> [4, 5, 7, 89, 4, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 4, 45, 56, 23, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 224, 234, 565, 546, 345, 23, 234, 234, 234, 23466, 25, 54]
>> y = x.select{|m| m>20 && m<200}
y = x.select{|m| m>20 && m<200}
=> [89, 45, 56, 23, 23, 25, 54]
```

One problem about this is obviously is the time penalty. Select has to go through all the values in that array and does a sequential check which would result this run in O(n) time. Is there a better alternative to select which does it in a lesser time. Space is not an issue for me.

I am talking on cases where the same select is being used repetitively. If I am going to use the same select conditions 1000 times in a loop for an array of size n, then I will have to do the operation like 1000 * n times. Whereas if its optimized for space, I would only be doing 1000 * 1 times.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to run a test on all values in an array, without testing all of those values in the array?

Comment: @The MYYN: On a real computer, that's still linear time unless I'm messing up my reasoning. Even if you have 24 workers on 24 cores, that's O(n/24), which is equivalent to O(n) — it's a constant factor. The only way you get O(1) is if you assume a computer that can perform an unlimited number of tasks at once (O(n/n) = O(1)), which is physically impossible.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa.. May be my problem was not clear. Let me edit the question for clarity

Comment: For what I understand, you are trying to use blocks (procs, perhaps?) as keys. Any reason for that? I'm tempted to say the simplest thing to do is a hash table, but that won't work with procs as keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to perform an operation on every element in an array in better than linear time — the idea sounds self-contradictory. You could memoize the result if you need to do the same calculation on the same array more than once to trade space for constant-time performance on subsequent runs, but I think O(n) is as good as it gets otherwise.

Comment: It is possible to have O(1) in cases where select has only one condition. I will be using the condition as a key for a hash, by this way it is directly transformed to O(1).  I am wondering how this is possible when the conditions increase.

Comment: @Bragboy: It is not really clear what you mean by using the condition as a key for a hash. Are you using a the hash as a sort of memoizer?

Comment: @MAK: Yes thats how any array will be converted to a hash

Comment: @Bragboy: How would you convert the array into a hash in O(1)? Don't you have to go over all elements?

Comment: @MAK: I mean for the first time (while constructing the hash), yes I will have to. but consecutive times the order will be in O(1)